# How should I declare a variable argument parameter

Tags: java, variadic-functions

```
public void foo(Integer... ids) {
    Integer... fIds = bar(ids);
}

public void bar(Integer... ids) {
// I would like to eliminate few ids and return a subset. How should I declare the return argument 
}
```

How should I declare the return type for bar?

Comment: I don't think the line `Integer... fIds = bar(ids);` is legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to vararg parameters as an array.

```
public Integer[] bar(Integer... ids) {
..
}
```

See [varargs docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

> It is still true that multiple arguments must be passed in an array, but the varargs feature automates and hides the process

To the jvm this is actually an array, and the compiler has hidden the creation of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Set `bar`'s return type to `Integer[]` and in `foo` specify `fIds` type as `Integer[]` too.

Answer (score 1):

Variable arguments parameters are just syntactic sugar for arrays, so you can just handle `ids` as an array of `Integer` (i.e. an `Integer[]`).

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
public Integer[] bar(Integer... ids) {
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer id : ids)
        if (shouldBeIncluded(id)) res.add(id);
    return res.toArray();
}
```